# Rewrite an one-layer neural network into infinite-layer equivalent network

Tags: normed-spaces, neural-networks

## Problem

In the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.06541.pdf) I am reading now, the author wrote generalized linear predictor with ReLU activation
$$\{\mathbf{x}\mapsto \sigma(\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}): \Vert\mathbf{w}\Vert_2\leq M\}$$ into a (possibly) infinitely-deep "super-thin" network with ReLU activation
$$
\left\{\mathbf{x} \mapsto \sigma\left(w_{d} \cdot \sigma\left(\ldots w_{2} \cdot \sigma\left(\mathbf{w}_{1}^{\top} \mathbf{x}\right)\right)\right) :\left\|\mathbf{w}_{1}\right\| \cdot \prod_{j=2}^{d}\left|w_{j}\right| \leq M\right\}
$$
and claim their **equivalence** and this motivates their following work to show that sample complexity of deep neural network could be independent of depth $d$.

One naive way to see this is to set $w_i=1,i=2,3,\cdots,d$, but I am not sure there is more "interesting" way to interpret this equivalence.